# Right align Ionic datetime picker's date on the label

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Do you have any clue to right align [**Ionic date picker**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#datetime). I have tried with `float-right` and `float-end`. But no luck :(

**Note:** I need to `right align` the final date on the `label`.

You can play with [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-razfc3?file=pages/home/home.html)

```
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label fixed>Compl. Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="completionDate" float-end></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Were you trying to align the popup, or the label?

Comment: Label. Final date on the label @Z.Bagley

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only possible way to maintain clickability of the label while aligning the datetime on the right (without additional custom code) is to have the date-time take up full 100% width and then text-align right as shown below.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>Compl. Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime  style="width: 100%; text-align: right;"displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="completionDate"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

You could also use `position: absolute; right: 0;` instead of the full width + text-align, but then you'd have to create a custom click function for the label to activate the date picker modal.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i have got it

```
    <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label style=" text-align: right;">Compl. Date</ion-label>
        <ion-datetime displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="completionDate" float-end></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: No. I need to right align the `date`.i.e. `2nd` component.